# Chrome Extension: browserAction.onClicked.addListener() not being called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a very simple Chrome extension. All it is at this point is a popup html file that tries to display an alert when the browser action icon is clicked. I am obviously doing something wrong because the alert doesn't fire.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Simple",
  "description": "Simple",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Simple",
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        //Executed when the extension's icon is clicked
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
        { 
            alert("gah");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

        function onPageLoad()
        {
            //Executed when the extension's icon is clicked
            chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
            { 
                alert("gah");
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="onPageLoad()">
    Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE BASED UPON RESPONSES**
Thank you for your response. I've made the following changes but is still not being called browser.Action.onClicked() (you can see that instead of an alert I am using console.log(). (The log at global scope is displayed, the one inside the callback is not).

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Simple",
  "description": "Simple",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
  }, 
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Simple",
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="white-space: nowrap">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
console.log("Running at global scope")

//Executed when the extension's icon is clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{ 
    console.log("Running insode of addListener()");
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked` can't be used inside a popup. It doesn't make much sense - you start listening for browser action icon being clicked after it was already clicked. It can be clicked again, but then popup will be closed and listener will be terminated before anything happens.
`chrome.browserAction.onClicked` is supposed to be used on the background page and only when popup for browser action is not used:

> This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup.

[source](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked)

You should probably just write:

```
<script>
        alert("gah");
</script>
```

But I'm not sure if alerts work in a popup. Better try something like:

```
<script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = "gah";
</script>
```

**EDIT**

There is one more thing to fix in your extension. As @Cody suggested in his answer, you shouldn't have used inline script. It is blocked for security reasons. Take the code I suggested above and put it into a separate javascript file, then include it in `popup.html` head:

```
<script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: Yep, made that change @KonradDzwinel - thank you. Unfortunately I still have the same issue. See my latest updates to the original question. (Thank you again for all of your help!)

Comment: 1. You can't use `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` in the popup. Please see top of my answer. 2. You don't need `"scripts": ["popup.js"]` in manifest, I don't know why @Cody suggested it. 3. The output from `console.log` won't be displayed in the main page devtools, it will be displayed in popup devtools. To open popup devtools: open a popup, right click on it, select 'inspect element'.

Answer (score 1):

According to revised Chrome Security Policies, the chrome extensions will no longer be able to use inline javascript in your popup.html http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#jsexecution

You will have to create a JS file and state about its existence in the Manifest.json as coded below:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Simple",
  "description": "Simple",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {    
    "scripts": ["bg.js"] //Here you can name the JS file that you have created
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Simple",
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        //Executed when the extension's icon is clicked         
            alert("gah");
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

You can get started building Chrome Extension following Manifest Version 2, taking reference from http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html and http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

Comment: This is a valid point to! I missed that in my answer. I just don't understand your example, what does `background``scripts` has to do with popup? He just needs to put popup script into external JS file and include it in popup.html header.

Comment: apart from that you also need to state in manifest file that you are going to use `<js-file-name>.js`, because it won't allow any external js file to execute unless the file has been mentioned in `manifest.json`

Comment: Sorry, I can't find it in the docs. It doesn't make sense to use file as a background script only if we want to use it in a popup. Also, I have a `manifest_version:2` extension that includes multiple js files in header and none of them is mentioned in `manifest.json`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses guys. I've updated the original question based upon your suggestions. I am still unable to get the onClicked handler to execute.