# chrome extension create tab not work in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

my extension works good later but when i upgrade my chrome version to 24 asked me to edit manifest to version 2 not install extension
not links in popup.html not working for me

```
<a href="" onclick=aa();>link 1</a><br>


function aa(){
chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://aaaa.com'});
}
```

> error: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:".

sincerely

Comment: already answered before on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706649/chrome-extension-browseraction-onclicked-addlistener-not-being-called/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to revised Chrome Security Policies, the chrome extensions will no longer be able to use inline javascript in your popup.html

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#jsexecution

You have to remove inline javascript, put it in a JS file and then load it from your HTML page.